# Сортировка JOIN

Tags: база-данных, сортировка, mysql

Здравствуйте! Есть такая задача: есть таблица с товарами и таблица с картинками к этому товару, к примеру, товары items (`id,name`) и картинки images (`id,item_id,image_file`), задача в том, чтобы одним запросом выдернуть товары и по одной последней картинке, могу выдергивать просто первую картинку.

```
SELECT i.*,im.image_file FROM items AS i LEFT JOIN images AS im ON i.id = im.item_id GROUP BY i.id
```

Вот если в таблице кimages к одному товару 3 фотки (например с id 1,2,3) то этим запросом мы получаем первую (id=1), вопрос в том, как отсортировать JOIN, чтобы на выходе получать не первую картинку, а последнюю с id = 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решилось так:

```
SELECT i.*,im.image_file FROM items AS i LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY id DESC) AS im ON i.id = im.item_id GROUP BY i.id
```